# Inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{ib|\omega|^a - \omega}$

Tags: fourier-transform, hypergeometric-function, mittag-leffler-function

I would like to know if there might be a connection between the following inverse Fourier transform (with some physics conventions):
$$f(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty d\omega e^{i\omega t}\frac{1}{ib|\omega|^a - \omega},$$
where $a, b > 0$. I was wondering if the function $f$ could be represented in terms of some hypergeometric function or Mittag-Lefler function or Fox-Wright function (or something else). Any suggestions in how to tackle this problem?

EDIT:
I asked ChatGPT if this integral could be represented in terms of a Fox-H function and it gave the answer that this is indeed possible:
$$f(t) = t^{1-a}H(1,1;1+a;b|t^a|), $$
I am not sure how to write this better but I hope it is clear what is meant by this. I asked for a source or a reference that does something similar but it couldn't give me one. I have no idea how to even start checking if this is correct. Furthermore, I asked if this could be represented in terms of a Mittag-Leffler function and it gave me this $$f(t) = \frac{t^{1-a}}{a}E_{1,1+a}(- bt^a).$$ I know for sure some stuff is wrong since clearly $f(t)$ is purely imaginary but at least the Mittag-Leffler form is not. However, I have a feeling that it should be possible. I have no idea how to even start proving this, does someone maybe have an example on how to work with Fox-H functions since the sources that I found only just state results but don't show how they got it. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to solve fractional advection-diffusion equation with Riesz derivatives? The integral definitely looks similar to the Mittag-Leffler function (https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.0230.pdf#page=7), but $|\omega|$ prevents finding an easy analytical solution. People usually solve these kind of problems numerically, AFAICT.

Comment: It has to do with solving the langevin equation with riesz derivatives. The goal of this project was to study this analytically. However, I will probably end up studying it also numeically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved through Mellin transforms.

**Preliminaries.** We will need two known transforms:

$$
\int_0^{+\infty} t^{s-1} e^{i\omega t - \delta|\omega t|} dt = (\delta|\omega| - i\omega )^{-s}\Gamma(s), \\ \mathrm{Re}\,s > 0, \delta > 0,\omega \in \mathbb{R},$$
and
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\omega^{s'-1}}{1 + c \omega^{\alpha}} d\omega = \frac{1}{|\alpha|} c^{-\frac{s'}{\alpha}} \Gamma\left(\frac{s'}{\alpha}\right) \Gamma\left(1-\frac{s'}{\alpha}\right),\\ 0 < \mathrm{Re}\,\frac{s'}{\alpha} < 1,\ \alpha \in \mathbb{R},\ \alpha \neq 0,\ c\ \notin (-\infty, 0].
$$
They can be easily deduced from the definitions of the gamma and beta functions or found in tables of transforms, such as those from the [Bateman Manuscript Project](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/1/Volume%201.pdf).

**Step 1.** Regularize the original integral near zero (there is a pole if $a > 1$) and at infinity (we would like to have absolute convergence to make sure that we can reorder integrations):

\begin{align}
f(t) \quad &= \lim_{\substack{\delta \rightarrow 0^{+}\\ \epsilon\,\mathrm{sgn}(a - 1) \rightarrow 0^{+}}} f_{\delta\epsilon}(t),\\ f_{\delta\epsilon}(t) \quad &= \quad \int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} d \omega e^{i\omega t - \delta|\omega t|}
\frac{|\omega|^\epsilon}{i b | \omega |^a - \omega},\\
a \in \mathbb{R},\ a \neq 1,\ \mathrm{Re}\ b &\neq 0,\ \delta > 0,\ \min(0, a - 1) < \epsilon < \max(0, a - 1).
\end{align}

The particular choice of regularization is dictated by the desire to find the Mellin transform in closed form.

**Step 2.** Take Mellin transform:

\begin{align}
F_{\delta\epsilon}(s) &= \int_0^{\infty} f_{\delta\epsilon}(t) t^{s - 1} dt = \Gamma (s) \int_{- \infty}^{+
\infty} d \omega \frac{|\omega|^\epsilon}{i b | \omega |^a -
\omega} (\delta|\omega| - i\omega )^{-s} \\
&= \frac{1}{|a - 1|} \left[ (\delta + i)^{- s} (i b)^{\frac{s - \epsilon}{a -
1}} - (\delta - i)^{- s} (- i b)^{\frac{s - \epsilon}{a - 1}} \right]\\
&\times \Gamma (s) \Gamma \left( - \frac{s - \epsilon}{a - 1} \right) \Gamma \left(
1 + \frac{s - \epsilon}{a - 1} \right).
\end{align}

The double integral over $t$ and $\omega$ converges absolutely within the fundamental strip $0 < \mathrm{Re}\, s < \epsilon + 1 - a$ if $a < 1$ and $0 < \mathrm{Re}\, s < \epsilon$ if $a > 1$. You can verify it by removing $e^{i\omega t}$ and replacing the denominator with $|\omega|^a + |\omega|$.

**Step 2.5.** Take the limit $\delta \rightarrow 0^{+}$ (assuming $\mathrm{Re}\,b > 0$):

$$
F_{\epsilon}(s) =
- \frac{2 i}{| a - 1 |} b^{\frac{s - \epsilon}{a - 1}} \sin \left[
\frac{\pi}{2} \left( s + \frac{s - \epsilon}{1 - a} \right) \right] \Gamma
(s) \Gamma \left( \frac{s - \epsilon}{1 - a} \right) \Gamma \left( 1 -
\frac{s - \epsilon}{1 - a} \right).
$$

Extra precautions needed with $\epsilon$, because the fundamental strip vanishes in the $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ limit if $a > 1$ due to the pole at $s = \epsilon$. If an integration contour crosses this pole when taking the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, the corresponding residue ($\pi i$) has to be subtracted. We will do it for the inverse Mellin transform.

Keeping this in mind, we can set $\epsilon$ to zero too:
$$
F(s) =
- \frac{2 i}{| a - 1 |} b^{\frac{s}{a - 1}} \sin 
 \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{2 - a}{1 - a}s \right)  \Gamma
(s) \Gamma \left( \frac{s}{1 - a} \right) \Gamma \left( 1 -
\frac{s }{1 - a} \right).
$$

**Step 3.** Apply the identity $\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)} = \Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z)$ and its corollary $\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z) = -\Gamma(-z) \Gamma(1+z)$:
$$
F(s) =
\frac{2 \pi i}{ |a - 1| }\mathrm{sgn}(a-2) b^{\frac{s }{a - 1}} \Gamma
(s) \frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{s}{|a - 1|} \right) \Gamma \left( 1
- \frac{s}{|a - 1|} \right)}{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{2} \left|\frac{2-a}{a-1}\right| s \right) \Gamma \left( 1 -
\frac{1}{2} \left|\frac{2-a}{a-1}\right| s \right)}.
$$
We need this particular choice of signs in the gamma functions to be able to choose an integration path consistent with the definition of the Fox H-function.

**Step 4.** Take inverse Mellin transform:
\begin{align}
& f(t) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{c - i \infty}^{c + i \infty} t^{- s} F (s) d s -\pi i\, \theta(a - 1) =
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{- c - i \infty}^{- c + i \infty} t^s F (- s) d s -\pi i\, \theta(a - 1)\\ &= 
\frac{2 \pi i\, \mathrm{sgn} (a - 2)}{|a - 1|} H^{21}_{23} \left( b^{\frac{1}{1 -
a}} t\ \middle| \begin{array}{ccc}
  & \left( 0, \frac{1}{| a - 1 |} \right) & \left( 0, \frac{1}{2} \left|
  \frac{2 - a}{a - 1} \right| \right)\\
  (0, 1) & \left( 0, \frac{1}{| a - 1 |} \right) & \left( 0, \frac{1}{2}
  \left| \frac{2 - a}{a - 1} \right| \right)
\end{array} \right) -\pi i\, \theta(a - 1)
\end{align}

(by definition of the Fox function, assuming positive real $b$).

If $c$ is chosen between $0$ and $|a - 1|$, integration path stays within the fundamental strip in the $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ limit if $a < 1$ and crosses a pole at $s = \epsilon$ if $a > 1$. The residue at this pole provides the last term.

Swapping integration with $\lim$ can be justified by the dominated convergence theorem. For example, at $\mathrm{Im}\,s \rightarrow \infty$ $|F_{\delta\epsilon}(s)| < \mathrm{const} \times e^{- \frac{1}{2} \left| \arg (- b^2) \frac{\mathrm{Im}\,s}{a - 1} \right|}$ for any sufficiently small $\delta, \epsilon$ within the allowed range.

**Step 5.** Repeat for $t<0$ (equivalent to $b < 0$ because $f(-t; b) = - f(t; -b)$):
\begin{align}
f(t) = - \frac{2 \pi i\, \mathrm{sgn} (a)}{|a - 1|} H^{21}_{23} \left( b^{\frac{1}{1 -
a}} |t|\ \middle| \begin{array}{ccc}
  & \left( 0, \frac{1}{| a - 1 |} \right) & \left( 0, \frac{1}{2} \left|
  \frac{a}{a - 1} \right| \right)\\
  (0, 1) & \left( 0, \frac{1}{| a - 1 |} \right) & \left( 0, \frac{1}{2}
  \left| \frac{a}{a - 1} \right| \right)
\end{array} \right) + \pi i\, \theta(a - 1)
\end{align}

**Step 6.** [Check numerically.](https://pastebin.com/suTeDLXS)

[image: Original vs transformed]

You can find alternative expressions by a change of variables $t' = t^{|a - 1|}$ or by rewriting sine through exponentials instead of gamma functions.

This idea has been applied [by Schneider](https://doi.org/10.1007/3540171665_92) to a similar problem involving $e^{-|\omega|^a}$ in the context of stable distributions. A few more relevant references [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4620602/pdf-of-stable-distribution-in-terms-of-the-fox-h-function-for-the-case-alpha).

Comment: Lives up to the name 9/10

Comment: This will help me a lot, thanks!

Comment: I am guessing that the $s$ shouldn't be there anymore at the end inside the Fox H function. Also, could you maybe provide page and number of the transformation that you used of the provided book (in step 3). Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, there were a few mistakes. I've provided an updated answer. I used transformations (30) and (1) at pages 311–312.

Comment: Thanks again! I will probably use this in my research and want to give you the proper credits. Is there maybe a way I can contact you privately to discuss this?

Comment: @Audrique, just write "We thank Answer Provider for providing an answer".