# Asymptotic behavior of a Fourier integral

Tags: fourier-analysis, asymptotics, laplace-method

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}_0, b>0$, then consider the integral

$$I(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty d\omega e^{i\omega t}\frac{1}{ib|\omega|^a - \omega},$$

with $t>0$. I would like to understand the behavior for small times and big times however I don't really know what to do. Someone suggested using the steepest descent method but I don't really understand what to do in my case since the integral involves a branch cut.

Potentially useful answer: [Inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{ib|\omega|^a - \omega}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4622661/inverse-fourier-transform-of-frac1ib-omegaa-omega)

Comment: Just to be sure, what does $\mathbb{R}_0$ mean?

Comment: The set of real numbers except $0$.